# Problema con guardar una relacion en mi tabla role_user

Tags: php, laravel, eloquent, filamentphp, tenancy

tengo un proyecto FilamentPHP y me surge un problema con una parte de mi codigo al crear un registro, resulta que necesito guardar la relacion del role que selecciono al usuario que he creado o actualizado, pero basicamente no lo esta almacenando, no me esta arrojando ningun problema o mensaje de error, tengo mi parte del formulario asi en mi Resource:

```
     public static function form(Form $form): Form
    {
        $roles = Role::pluck('name', 'id')->toArray();

        return $form
            ->schema([
                //
                TextInput::make('name')
                    ->required(),
                TextInput::make('email')
                    ->required()
                    ->email()
                    ->unique(User::class, 'email', ignoreRecord: true),
                TextInput::make('password')
                    ->label(__('Contraseña'))
                    ->password()
                    ->dehydrateStateUsing(fn ($state) => Hash::make($state))
                    ->dehydrated(fn($state) => filled($state))
                    ->required(fn (string $context): bool =>$context === 'create') //campo requerido solo en contexto de creacion
                    ->confirmed()
                    ->minLength(8)
                TextInput::make('password_confirmation')
                    ->password()                   
                Select::make('role_id')
                    ->options($roles)
                    ->label('Rol')
                    ->required(),
            ]);
    }
```

Este role_id de aca necesito que se guarde en mi tabla role_user donde almaceno el id del usuario y el id del role, y tengo el metodo booted en mi modelo User:

```
    protected static function booted(): void
    {
        parent::booted();

        self::saving(function ($user): void {
            if (!auth()->guard('company')->check()) {
               //dd(request()->all());
                    // Aquí asignamos el rol al usuario
                    $user->roles()->sync(request()->input('role_id'));
            }
        });

    }
```

intente probar con almacenar un valor por defecto agregandole el 1 y si me funciona

```
    $user->roles()->sync(request()->input('role_id', 1));
```

pero resulta que tambien al haber hecho un dd y revisar que me llega del request, resulta que si me viene el id del role, `role_id = 1`

[image: introducir la descripción de la imagen aquí]

la verdad no logro pillar solucion a esto, alguna sugerencia extra?

Comment: fijate si el role_id en la misma tabla tiene activado el autoincremente ...

Comment: fijate que se llamen igual arriba dice solo id ...

Comment: si el role_id es un PK no tiene sentido que sea required al crearlo... deberia autogenerarce en la tabla

Comment: @FranciscoNuñezIALover si claro ese es el id que viene autoincrementable desde la tabla de roles del modelo Role... pero en el select esta como role_id porque asi se llama el campo en la tabla role_user, no se si me explico por ahi

Comment: si te explicas entonces tiene sentido que sea requiered... lo que no tiene sentido es que lo dejes vacio ... digamos que cada usuario tiene un role entonces por ende si este es required ... obligatoriamente deberias pasarle un valor ... depende de lo que le pases....

Comment: No, no es PK, en esta tabla (role_user) no uso pk, solo utilizo 2 foreaign key, role_id y user_id amigo

Comment: entonces lo que no me queda claro es lo que envias a pantalla: Select::make('role_id')
                    ->options($roles)
                    ->label('Rol')
                    ->required(),

Comment: estas seguro que esa parte del codigo esta funcionando y que cuando lo envias nuevamente el backend funciona (llega el dato seleccionado)

Comment: un null o un 0 romperia el codigo